# Python Subprocess Pass in url to a program to run

Tags: python, subprocess

i have a problem i need help with. I am trying to use subprocess that will call my 2nd script that will use request to take the value im passing in for the URL and make a request for health check. I am having problems passing in URL in subprocess.

```
import subprocess 
protocol = http
HOSTNAME = 192.168.1.1
IDValue = health_check


url = protocol + "://" + HOSTNAME + "/" + IDValue 

#### Call 2nd script with url as input 2nd script is looking for a response. #### 
subprocess.call("python 2nd_python_script.py {url}", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but I see some issues with the code:

1. protocol, HOSTNAME, and IDValue seem like you wanted them to be strings - if this is the case, you'll need to put their values in 'single quotes' or "double quotes", e.g.

```py
protocol = "http"
HOSTNAME = "192.168.1.1"
IDValue = "health_check" # not sure whether this is what you intended
```

2. To use literal string interpolation (`"abc {variable}"`) in python, you need to put an 'f' infront of your string, e.g. `f"python 2nd_python_script.py {url}"`; this is known as an f-string ([more info here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)).
3. [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) takes a list of string arguments as input to use as shell arguments rather than a single string with all arguments; in your case, this would look like `subprocess.call(["python", "2nd_python_script.py", url])` in your case.

Also if you're looking to clean up your code, some recommendations:

1. For consistency, I'd recommend having the casing & names of your variables consistent - generally in python we use snake_case for all variables, so perhaps name your variables `protocol, hostname, id_value`.
2. `id_value` could use a better name - perhaps `endpoint`?
3. You can use an f-string for your url, e.g. `url = f"{protocol}://{hostname}/{id_value}"`.